# "Use of uninitialized value $prop_value in scalar chomp at configure line 473" OpenDDS configuration

Tags: windows, visual-studio, perl, data-distribution-service, opendds

I am trying to configure OpenDDS library with Windows 11 and Visual Studio 2022.

I ran the configure file through the Visual Studio Command Prompt and I get the following error.

```
Downloading ACE+TAO 2.2a with latest patches
Extracting archive ACE+TAO-2.2a_with_latest_patches_NO_makefiles.zip
Use of uninitialized value $prop_value in scalar chomp at configure line 473.
Couldn't get submodule.tools/rapidjson.openddsConfigureCommit from .gitmodules
Stopped at configure line 475.
ERROR: configure failed with errorcode 1
```

The configure.cmd file has the following code

```
@echo off
:: Win32 configure script wrapper for OpenDDS
:: Distributed under the OpenDDS License.
:: See: http://www.opendds.org/license.html

for %%x in (perl.exe) do set PERLPATH=%%~dp$PATH:x
if "x%PERLPATH%"=="x" (
  echo ERROR: perl.exe was not found.  This script requires Perl.
  exit /b 1
)
set PERLPATH=
perl configure %*
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  echo ERROR: configure failed with errorcode %errorlevel%
  exit /b %errorlevel%
)
if exist setenv.cmd call setenv.cmd
```

And I believe the configure file with perl is here https://github.com/objectcomputing/OpenDDS/blob/master/configure

I cross referenced this question ["Use of uninitialized value in scalar chomp" in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822049/use-of-uninitialized-value-in-scalar-chomp-in-perl), but I unfortunately do not code in Perl so I do not know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is about a pipe file handle that has failed to read what it was supposed to, as described in the code you linked. Line 473 is inside this relatively brief subroutine:

```
sub git_submodule_prop {
  my $path = shift;
  my $prop_name = shift;
  my $full_prop_name = "submodule.$path.$prop_name";
  open(my $fd, "-|", "git config --file .gitmodules --get $full_prop_name")
    or die("git_submodule_prop open failed: $!\nStopped");
  my $prop_value = <$fd>;
  close($fd);
  chomp($prop_value);
  if (!$prop_value) {
    die("Couldn't get $full_prop_name from .gitmodules\nStopped");
  }
  return $prop_value;
}
```

The error message says nothing especially noteworthy, except that the function `chomp` is used on an undefined value. The "real" error message comes below it:

```
Couldn't get submodule.tools/rapidjson.openddsConfigureCommit from .gitmodules
Stopped at configure line 475.
```

In the code you can see it tries to open a pipe to a `git` process, which apparently did open (because it did not die there), but then does not read anything from the file handle

```
my $prop_value = <$fd>;
```

Which then causes the code to die.

```
  if (!$prop_value) {
    die("Couldn't get $full_prop_name from .gitmodules\nStopped");
  }
```

What you need to investigate, perhaps, is why the `git` process did not read anything from the pipe.

Comment: Author of the code in question here, I think this is fixed now. This was a weird bug that had to do with how Perl on Windows works: https://github.com/objectcomputing/OpenDDS/pull/3812

Comment: @FredHornsey Good you got it fixed, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Like @TLP mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/a/74026678/8869703, it was indeed a failure with git.

The compressed file from OpenDDS did not contain a git package, so I could not rely on the file from https://opendds.org/downloads.html.

I followed the following steps that I found from the comments by @simpsont-oci here https://github.com/objectcomputing/OpenDDS/discussions/3784 :

- `git clone https://github.com/objectcomputing/OpenDDS.git`
- In the OpenDDS folder -> `git submodule init`
- `git submodule update`
- Through the VS Command Line `configure`

This worked for me.